# Panel shadow missing under unity

Tags: 11.10, unity, compiz

I no longer have a shadow under the panel in Unity on the account I use. I don't know the exact moment when the shadow disappeared. Might have happened after a unity crash (it crashed a lot).

I created another account and using that account I get the panel shadow.

How do I make it reappear under my "normal" account?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a hunch, I re-enabled "Have file manager handle the desktop" under Desktop in Advanced Settings (gnome-tweak-tool) and the panel shadow reappeared. I don't get why the two are related.

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

`unity-window-decorator --replace`

Answer (score 0):

Atm the shadow is drawn on the desktop and requires the Png plugin to be enabled, so check to see if Png is enabled in ccsm (Image Loading section

Be aware that (re)enabling that plugin may go fine or cause a hang up. If it does hang, (**give it at least 30 sec**),  then do a `Ctrl+Alt+print+K` & you should be ok when logging back in. (print is the Prnt Scrn on many keyboards

Comment: The png plugin is enabled. :(

Comment: On a hunch, I re-enabled "Have file manager handle the desktop" under Desktop in Advanced Settings (gnome-tweak-tool) and the panel shadow reappeared. I don't get why the two are related.

Comment: with "Have file manager handle the desktop" disabled nothing is 'drawn' on the Desktop which includes the shadow. (As mentioned atm the shadow is on the desktop, not part of the panel